# Multiple calls for one single function in Javascript

Tags: javascript

In order to shorten my code, 
I wonder if it's possible call the same function from many objects at the same time.

Something like:

```
[person, company, city].name();
```

Instead of:

```
person.name();
city.name();
company.name();
```

Is there something similar that I could do?

Comment: I don't think that is possible, you've call them separately

Comment: Short-code doesn't mean the best code. Instead of shortening code, optimize it

Comment: You can put them all in an array, then loop over the array, but unless you have quite a few objects, that loop is going to be longer.

Answer (score 3):

If you insist

```
[person, company, city].forEach(function(fn) { 
    fn.name(); 
});
```

generic

```
Array.prototype.callFn = function (arr, fName) {
    arr.forEach(function(fn) {
        fn[fName]();
    })
}
[person, company, city].callFn('name');
```

> ***WARNING**: Some say a warning is needed when extending the prototype of built-in objects - so, you are warned that this heinous act of javascript treason is being perpetrated in the second "generic" version of the code*

Comment: `In order to shorten my code` this has increased LoC

Comment: Fun fact: This code is 50% longer than the individual invocations. It also made it harder to read. (Both are a problem with the OP's request, not with the answer)

Comment: @Cerbrus And **slower**. Processing array loop

Comment: I laugh during a minute with your "If you insist". Hahahaha so good. Really this code is the same that call individually, I hope user explain for what he needs it. Call to a function of various objects simultaneous does not return any valid value, so it is impossible.

Comment: @Tushar - if you think 3 is `many objects`, then yes, this "solution" is longer - what if there were 200 objects in the array? Is this code longer or shorter :D

Comment: If there were 200 objects, you wouldn't hardcode the function calls in the first place.

Comment: I'd add an (additional) warning note about extending the prototype of built-in objects, such as array.

Comment: @Tushar I agree, but I don't judge :p - I honestly hope the OP is reading the comments and learning from the discussion in them

Comment: I also laugh with "if you insist", it was funny haha.

Comment: And about the code.. the real case are many variables calling a `datepicker()` (jQuery) that might be longer in the future. that's why I asked that